# Where can you release eensy weensy helpful little .NET classes?

Tags: .net, components, release

I find myself writing a lot of reusable code because I couldn't find reusable code that other people wrote. Tiny stuff, like little winforms components, among other things.

I am looking for a website where I could release this sort of stuff to the public with licensing on it. I don't need something like Google Code/Sourceforge/Codeplex, as it's too big for tiny classes that I know can help others. Something like [the PHP Classes Repository](http://www.phpclasses.org/), but for .NET.

I don't need things like version control, forums, wikis, issue trackers... I just want a place to share code quickly and easily.

Does a such a site exist?

As I realized when I was commenting on an answer, the ideal vision of what I'm looking for (in my head) is something like **the "flickr" of code**. Something where I can toss up a package of source, write a brief description, tag it, and be done with it. If something like that doesn't exist, maybe I just found my next side project.

[Joe answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1614391/where-can-you-release-eensy-weensy-helpful-little-net-classes/1614506#1614506) with [CodeKeep](http://www.codekeep.net/home.aspx) which is almost EXACTLY what I'm looking for, but it doesn't handle things like licensing, and it's almost a little too basic. But this is the closest so far.

EDIT:
I should have mentioned, all these things are generally unrelated, and I don't want to package them all up together.

Comment: I know I have heard of a ".net contrib" project that someone created with a very similar goal, but for the life of me I can't find it now.

Comment: On Ruby there is the ActiveSupport library (which comes from the RubyOnRails framework) with a lot of really useful stuff. There's a similar approach for .NET over here: http://code.google.com/p/activesupportnet/ Maybe a good place to try to merge your stuff into.

Comment: Aye ActiveSupport is pretty cool. That's a little too specific though.

Comment: If it's not big / complex enough for SourceForge etc, I don't see that it would be big enough to need a license.  I certainly wouldn't be prepared to agree to a license for small code snippets that I find from a google search.

Comment: How could something be "too small" to require a license? Intellectual property is intellectual property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[CodeKeep](http://www.codekeep.net/) is another site that is used for this. The bonus is that they have Visual Studio addins that allow you to search through these code chunks right from your IDE.

Comment: This is almost EXACTLY what I was looking for, except it doesn't cover things like licensing and stuff.

Answer (score 11):

There's http://www.codeproject.com/ and http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/

Comment: MSDN looks pretty close to what I was looking for.

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend the [Microsoft Code Gallery](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/) for general purpose C# classes/utilities.  They will take lots of small submissions.

For small WPF and Silverlight samples, the [Microsoft Expression Community Gallery](http://gallery.expression.microsoft.com/) works very well, and gets a fair amount of exposure.

Comment: Yeah i'm leaning more and more toward Code Gallery. I know it's going to be indexed well and that means a greater probability that someone will find my helpful eensy weensy classes.

Comment: I've used it in the past - The expression one is great - I got a good hundred downloads on one sample in about a week, which is good for something that was never advertised.

Answer (score 3):

You can post it on [codeplex](http://www.codeplex.com/) Or build you a little page and put the files [sourceforge](http://sourceforge.com)

Comment: CodePlex and Sourceforge are too big for this kind of stuff, comparable to Google Code.

Comment: Sorry but I don't see any different between CodePlex and Google Code

Answer (score 3):

My recommendation is start a blog and post all of your content there. Then have your source files on an associated: SourceForge, CodeProject, Assembla etc source hosting. I personally use Assembla, they offer free hosting for open source projects and give you SVN, web space, collaboration software etc.

Comment: This might be a good idea.. but a blog may get lost to the tubes of obscurity. Assembla looks pretty good.

Comment: You'd be surprised, if you create meaningful content it can syndicate forever. On my blog 2 of my shortest posts that were almost just one liners that solved problems that people made needlessly complex still brings in 100 of hits per month to them specifically. Even though they were written back in early 08.

Answer (score 2):

[CodeProject.com](http://www.codeproject.com/) sounds like what you're looking for. Also maybe [codeguru.com](http://www.codeguru.com/).

Comment: CodeGuru is more like a tutorial/article site similar to CodeProject. I want somewhere that I can just toss up some source, tag it, declare my license, and be done with it.... and hopefully others can find it. I guess I want Flickr for code. Har har.

Answer (score 0):

You could just start a project on CodePlex and your project would essentially be the "Eensy Weensy Helpful .NET Classes Repository" or whatever you want to call it. That's what I suggest anyway.

Comment: Not a bad idea.. but most of these classes are completely unrelated. Doesn't make much sense to package them all together, and I think they would get lost as a group.